# German language hyphenation on Mac

Tags: babel, hyphenation, languages

I am working in a file on a Mac using TexStudio in conjunction with MikTex. Unfortunately, no words are hyphenated at the end of the line, generating many line-overruns. 
The error log says:
ngermanb.ldf: Package babel warning: no hyphenation patterns were preloaded for the language "German (new orthography)" into the format.

I have spent some time online searching for solutions but have not been successful so far. I have come across commands to be run (not sure where to enter them) and would be thankful for a Mac-specific answer / instruction.

Many thanks

Christian

Comment: MiKTeX on a Mac? Oh, dear!

Comment: @egreg Would appreciate a helpful answer. If that is a combination one should not use, why not propose something actionable?

Comment: Sorry, that was a bit of a joke. I have always installed the various versions of MacTeX, that come once a year, and have found no problem like several MiKTeX users on Windows show here.